# Unable to create DB trace using DEA

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I want to create a DB trace file using DEA(Database Experimentation Assistant). I am using below softwares:

-SQL Server Express 2012 on Win10 machine where my DB is present.

-DEA is installed on a separate win10 machine.

When I am trying to capture the trace using DEA, it is giving me below error:

> Unable to start the trace on the target SQL Server, please check if
>   you have required permissions and SQL Server account has write access
>   to the specified trace file path. | Sql Error Code (19062)

On both my machine, Windows user have admin rights
-'Alter Trace' permission is granted to that DB user, which I am passing to DEA.
-Using that user, I am able to access the DB using SQL Management Studio from the machine where DEA is installed.

Answer (score 1):

DEA saves the trace files on the target server, not on your client machine (assuming you run DEA on your machine). So the path (folder) has to exist on the target server, and the SQL Server account needs write access to that.